# A better way than having 3 nested for loops to get data I need

Tags: c#, linq, nested-loops

I can build a dictionary with the way I'm curretnly doing but I was wondering if there was a better and faster way. I'm trying to use LINQ SelecMany statement but having trouble.

```
var replyChildren = reply.Children[0];
Dictionary<int, string> slowLog = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < replyChildren.Children.Count(); i++)
{
    var ithReplyChildren = replyChildren.Children[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        if (j == 3)
        {
            var jthReplyChildren = ithReplyChildren.Children[j];
            for (int k = 0; k < jthReplyChildren.Count; k++)
            {
                serverInfo += jthReplyChildren.Children[k].TextData; //+ "::";
            }
            break;
        }
        serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[j].TextData + ":";
    }
    slowLog.Add(i, serverInfo);
    serverInfo = "";
}
```

Reply will have children inside(0th element) then inside those it will have children and so on. The second for loop will only have 4 children and the 4th one will have to go one step deeper and get the children of that.

Comment: What type is `reply`?

Comment: just one tricky world - recursion ... better to wrap nested loops inside new methods - that will made you code more readable

Comment: Are there any children in `ithReplyChildren.Children[0].Children`, `ithReplyChildren.Children[1].Children` or `ithReplyChildren.Children[2].Children`?  If yes, why aren't they being logged? If no, then you can simplify your loop considerably by taking advantage of the fact that these collections are empty.

Comment: Why use a `Dictionary`? We already have a data structure that is a dictionary indexed by contiguous integer ranges starting from zero; it's called `List`.

Comment: Why do you care about *faster*? It looks like you're building a small logging lookup table. Is that the slowest thing in your program? If not, then who cares if there's a way to make it *faster*?  Make it easier to read, debug, maintain; that gives better return on investment.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Step one: stop using a dictionary. We already have a data structure that maps dense, zero-based integer ranges onto data: `List<T>`.  Refactor:

```
static string GetServerInfo(Thing thing)
{
  string serverInfo = "";
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    if (j == 3)
    {
      var jthReplyChildren = thing.Children[j];
      for (int k = 0; k < jthReplyChildren.Count; k++)
      {
        serverInfo += jthReplyChildren.Children[k].TextData; //+ "::";
      }
      break;
    }
    serverInfo += thing.Children[j].TextData + ":";
  }
  return serverInfo;
}
```

And now your main program is:

```
List<string> slowLog = reply.Children[0].Children.Select(GetServerInfo).ToList();
```

Now we have eliminated one loop and reduced the problem to making `GetServerInfo` look less horrible.

Unroll the outer loop:

```
static string GetServerInfo(Thing thing)
{
  string serverInfo = "";
  serverInfo += thing.Children[0].TextData + ":";
  serverInfo += thing.Children[1].TextData + ":";
  serverInfo += thing.Children[2].TextData + ":";
  var fourthChild = thing.Children[3];
  for (int k = 0; k < fourthChild.Count; k++)
    serverInfo += fourthChild.Children[k].TextData;
  return serverInfo;
}
```

Great, now we are down to one loop. Eliminate that loop:

```
static string GetServerInfo(Thing thing)
{
  string serverInfo = "";
  serverInfo += thing.Children[0].TextData + ":";
  serverInfo += thing.Children[1].TextData + ":";
  serverInfo += thing.Children[2].TextData + ":";
  serverInfo += string.Join("", thing.Children[3].Children.Select(x => x.TextData));
  return serverInfo;
}
```

We can use Join for the others too:

```
static string GetServerInfo(Thing thing)
{
  string firstThree = string.Join("", thing.Children.Take(3).Select( x => x.TextData + ":"));
  string fourth = string.Join("", thing.Children[3].Children.Select(x => x.TextData));
  return firstThree + fourth;
}
```

Reduce further:

```
static string GetServerInfo(Thing thing)
{
  return 
    string.Join("", thing.Children.Take(3).Select(x => x.TextData + ":")) +
    string.Join("", thing.Children[3].Children.Select(x => x.TextData));
}
```

Use arrow notation:

```
static string GetServerInfo(Thing thing) => 
    string.Join("", thing.Children.Take(3).Select(x => x.TextData + ":")) +
    string.Join("", thing.Children[3].Children.Select(x => x.TextData));
```

Wait a minute, now we have a lambda.  Rewrite the original site:

```
List<string> slowLog = reply.Children[0].Children
  .Select(thing => 
    string.Join("", thing.Children.Take(3).Select(x => x.TextData + ":")) +
    string.Join("", thing.Children[3].Children.Select(x => x.TextData)))
  .ToList();
```

And we are down to a single statement. **No loops; no loop problems.**  The logic is very clearly expressed -- take three of these, join them together, blah blah blah, turn it into a list, done.

Can we go even further?  Sure! We can combine the select and concatenate operators in a helper and make our program more *fluent*:

```
public static string SelectConcat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, string> f) =>
  string.Join("", items.Select(f));
```

And now our program becomes

```
List<string> slowLog = reply.Children[0].Children
  .Select(thing => 
    thing.Children.Take(3).SelectConcat(x => x.TextData + ":") +
    thing.Children[3].Children.SelectConcat(x => x.TextData))
  .ToList();
```

And now it is *very* clear what we are doing.

The takeaway here is: the goal is not to make the program *small*; this isn't code golf.  It's **to make the code read more like its intended semantics**.

Your original code made it look like the most important thing in the program fragment is the values of the loop indices; look at how much screen real estate is devoted to i, j and k. Those are *mechanisms*.  Write your code to emphasize the *meaning*.  If you mean "take the first three", then there should be a `Take(3)` in there somewhere, not a `for` loop.

How do we get from the initial program that emphasizes the values of i, j and k to a program that describes the operations on the data? See what I did there: I made a series of small, easy refactorings, each of which *raises the level of abstraction* to make the code read more like its intended semantics or eliminated unnecessary "ceremony".

Comment: Out of interest, any reason for `string.Join("", ...)` rather than `string.Concat(...)`?

Comment: @James: Nope, no particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not near an IDE to test this, but I got it down a bit in size:

```
var replyChildren = reply.Children[0];
Dictionary<int, string> slowLog = new Dictionary<int, string>();

int i = 0;
foreach (var child in replyChildren.Children)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:", child.Children[0].TextData);
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:", child.Children[1].TextData);
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}:", child.Children[2].TextData);

    sb.Append(string.Join(string.Empty, child.Children[3].Select(x => x.TextData));

    slowLog.Add(i, sb.ToString());
    i++;
}
```

I don't exactly know your requirements, but as @EricLippert mentioned in the comments, you could just use a `List<string>`...

Comment: You're doing the Append inside a *Select()* ??  Eeeek!  Using Aggregate would be a bit better...

Comment: Yeah Im making that edit now, I was in a meeting haha

Comment: Select would look much better in this case. Aggregate will over complicate what you're trying to do. Your first method was extremely self explanatory, i don't know why you would use aggregate for this. On top of that, Aggregate is removing the purpose of stringbuilder in the first place, every aggregate function will create a new string to then be appeneded to the stringbuilder, removing the optimization you would get from appending each line separately.

Comment: @Dispersia: **Never** write a select that has a side effect. A select should **select something**, not cause an effect. It might work in a simple query, and then a small refactoring can cause your query to start behaving very oddly indeed.

Comment: Select is entirely inappropriate here. Aggregate is better, in the sense that it is designed to solve this problem, but we already have a special version of Aggregate designed to solve the problem of appending strings: `string.Join`.  Use it!

Comment: @EricLippert I was less suggesting towards the use of select, more to something other than aggregate. if Children[j] is a list, you could foreach on it, but Aggregate seems incredibly wrong here as well. Why use a stringbuilder at all if you're just going to concatenate the data anyway?

Comment: @EricLippert I reached my comment upvote limit for the day, but thanks.  I was doing the refactoring in the answer textbox and just had a brain fart.  StringBuilder isnt needed at all for the combination of the items in `Children[i]`.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First step, let's unroll the middle loop:

```
var replyChildren = reply.Children[0];
Dictionary<int, string> slowLog = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < replyChildren.Children.Count(); i++)
{
    var ithReplyChildren = replyChildren.Children[i];
    serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[0].TextData + ":";
    serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[1].TextData + ":";
    serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[2].TextData + ":";
    var jthReplyChildren = ithReplyChildren.Children[3];
    for (int k = 0; k < jthReplyChildren.Count; k++)
    {
        serverInfo += jthReplyChildren.Children[k].TextData;//+ "::";
    }

    slowLog.Add(i, serverInfo);
    serverInfo = "";
}
```

then we'll replace teh `for()`s with `foreach(()`

```
var replyChildren = reply.Children[0];
var slowLog = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int i = 0;

foreach(var ithReplyChildren in replyChildren.Children)
{
    serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[0].TextData + ":";
    serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[1].TextData + ":";
    serverInfo += ithReplyChildren.Children[2].TextData + ":";

    var jthReplyChildren = ithReplyChildren.Children[3];
    foreach (var kthReplyChildren in jthReplyChildren.Children)
    {
        serverInfo += kthReplyChildren.TextData;//+ "::";
    }

    slowLog.Add(i++, serverInfo);
    serverInfo = "";
}
```

And then Mike's suggestion of using `StringBuilder`

```
var replyChildren = reply.Children[0];
var slowLog = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int i = 0;

foreach (var ithReplyChildren in replyChildren.Children)
{
    var serverInfo = new StringBuilder();
    serverInfo.Append(ithReplyChildren.Children[0].TextData);
    serverInfo.Append(':');

    serverInfo.Append(ithReplyChildren.Children[1].TextData);
    serverInfo.Append(':');
    serverInfo.Append(ithReplyChildren.Children[2].TextData);
    serverInfo.Append(':');

    var jthReplyChildren = ithReplyChildren.Children[3];
    foreach (var kthReplyChildren in jthReplyChildren.Children)
    {
        serverInfo.Append(kthReplyChildren.TextData);
    }

    slowLog.Add(i++, serverInfo.ToString());
}
```